# Дать класс родителю элемента через DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как дать класс объекту UL если у нас есть такая структура:

```html
<div class="c1">
  <ul>
    <li class="item-catalog">Text</li>
    <li class="item-catalog">Text</li>
    <li class="item-catalog">Text</li>
    <li class="item-catalog">Text</li>
    <li class="item-catalog">Text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Причем мне нельзя трогать блок с классом c1, нужно отталкиваться только от LI.item-catalog и через него дать класс родителю, то есть UL.

Comment: `.parent().addClass()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
querySelector('.item-catalog').parentNode.classList.add('class');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('li.item-catalog').closest('ul').addClass();
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите более развернутые ответы и рабочий код.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?